# Remove max-width from hugo example

Tags: css, width, hugo, blogdown

I've made a website using the academic theme of hugo; there's an example provided [here](https://themes.gohugo.io//theme/academic/post/). I want all of my posts (of which there are three examples provided at the link) to be wider. For example, a post initially looks like this:
[image: original width]
where the text is constrained within a more narrow window, but I want it to look like this:
[image: wider width]
where the text has the same width as the page.

I notice that I can make this happen by unchecking the 'max-width' specification in '.article-container'. How can I edit my local files for my personal page with the academic theme to make it so this automatically happens?

Answer (score 5):

This may be done by overriding the CSS in the `.article-container` selector.

```
.article-container {
   max-width: none;
}
```

The simpler way is to create a file `layouts/partials/custom_head.html` where you place the above CSS rule inside a `<style>...</style>` block.

Another way is to create a file `assets/css/custom.css` with that rule, and then updating the property `plugins_css` in the file `config/_default/params.toml` so that the new stylesheet can be included as part of the loaded stylesheets.

```
plugins_css = ["custom"]
```